# странная фаза Гауссовского пучка 2D

Tags: python-3.x, fft

Я имею Гауссовский пучок 2D:
[image: Пучок]

С помощью использования fft2 и angle я получил следующие результаты:
[image: Результат 1]
[image: Результат 2]

```
def finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx):
    f = np.array([[0.0]*N]*N)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            f[i][k] = np.exp(-(x[i]*x[i] + y[k]*y[k]))

    D1 = fftpack.fft2(f)
    D2 = fftpack.fftshift(D1)

    b = N*N/(4*a*M)
    x = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    y = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.imshow(np.abs(D2))
    plt.show()

    plt.imshow(np.angle(D2))
    plt.show(True)
    return D2

a = 5
N = 128
M = 256
b = N*N/(4*a*M)
hx = 2*a/N
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
y = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx)
```

Но фаза должна была получиться 0 или близкая к 0.
Помогите исправить.